# SPSS Plotting a scatterplot with categorical variable - i actually want it to scatter

Tags: spss

I'm trying to plot a scatterplot in SPSS where one of the variables is categorical (binary). However I want it to actually scatter like a normal scatterplot and not have all my cases divided into the two groups.

Comment: Try to convert the variable into numeric (recommendation: create a new variable)

Comment: " Is this possible" is not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a type node in front of the graphic node and put measure = *continuous*. You also can try to use a recode node or even a derive node just to change for a continuous variable.